# Blender Grid Scale Setting Issue

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, snapping, unreal-engine

how to set grid setting and UV grid setting in blender
in power of 2's (1.0, 2.0, 4.0,8.0,16.0)meters for creating modular assets.